Lifting a particular homotopy commutative diagram
This question has been asked in some capacity before, but usually with extra assumptions on the maps (e.g. one of the maps is a cofibration). Let's work in the category of pointed topological spaces. Given a homotopy commutative diagram of the form
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> Y \\
@VfVV @VVgV \\
X' @>>> Y'
\end{CD}
$$
is it possible to replace $g: Y \to Y'$ with a map $g': Z \to Z'$, such that

We have homotopy equivalences $\alpha: Y \to Z$ and $\beta: Y' \to Z'$ such that $g' = \beta \circ g \circ \alpha^{-1}$ in the homotopy category,

and furthermore the following diagram commutes (on the nose):
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> Z \\
@VfVV @VVg'V \\
X' @>>> Z'
\end{CD}
$$
The horizontal maps are maps "homotopic to the originals," obtained by transferring across the equivalence between $Y, Y'$ and $Z, Z'$. We may assume that all spaces are CW complexes. I'm particularly interested in the case where the diagram "looks like a morphism of spectra," i.e. we have for each $n$ a morphism $f_n: X_n \to Y_n$ such that the diagram for each $n$
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Sigma X_n @>>> X_{n+1} \\
@V\Sigma f_nVV @VVf_{n+1}V \\
\Sigma Y_n @>>> Y_{n+1}
\end{CD}
$$
commutes up to homotopy, where the horizontal maps are the structure maps for each spectrum; it is possible to edit both spectra level-wise up to homotopy to get some map which actually defines a morphism of spectra?

What do you mean by "under these identifications, $g'$ corresponds to $g$"? The way you set up the problem, there's no obvious meaning to the word "corresponds". Do you want the replacement to be functorial in some way, or the equivalences fixed so that you can transfer $g$ along them?

The latter—we have homotopy equivalences $\alpha: Y \to Z$ and $\beta: Y' \to Z'$ such that in the homotopy category, $g' = \beta \circ g \circ \alpha^{-1}$. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Do you want $X\to Z$ to be equal to $X\to Y\xrightarrow{\alpha} Z$ or is homotopic enough? In the latter case you can simply replace $g$ by a fibration $p\colon Z\to Y'$ and lift the homotopy $h\colon X\times I\to Y'$ making the diagram commute to $H\colon X\times I\to Z$.

@VincentBoelens Just homotopic is enough—thank you for the response! If you leave your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Let $h\colon X\times I\to Y'$ be a homotopy that makes the diagram commute, i.e. $h_0$ is equal to going through the upper right corner and $h_1$ is equal to going through the lower left corner of the diagram. We can factor $g$ as $Y\xrightarrow{s} Z\xrightarrow{p}Y'$, where $s$ is a homotopy equivalence and $p$ a fibration. Lift $h$ to a homotopy $H\colon X\to Z$ such that $H_0$ is equal to $X\to Y\xrightarrow{s} Z$.
The diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>H_1>> Z \\
@VfVV @VVpV \\
X' @>>> Y'
\end{CD}$$
commutes on the nose by construction and is the desired replacement.
